# Why the EntityManager is closed even if transaction has been committed?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am making some simple tests with JPA and Hibernate and I happen to have the EntityManager closed when I don't expect to.

Here's my test main:

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBResourcesManager.initPeristence();
        List<Event> allEvents = EventDao.findAllEventsA();
        Event e1 = new Event("Event", new Date());
        EventDao.store(e1);
        DBResourcesManager.shutdown();
    }
}
```

DB helper:

```
public class DBResourcesManager {

    private static EntityManager entityManager;
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public static void initPeristence() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Entity and corresponding DAO:

```
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
/*...*/
}

public class EventDao {
    public static void store(Event e) {
        EntityManager em = DBResourcesManager.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
        t.begin();
        em.persist(e);
        t.commit();
        em.close();
    }

    public static List<Event> findAllEventsA() {
        EntityManager em = DBResourcesManager.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
        t.begin();
        List<Event> events = em.createQuery("from Event", Event.class)
                .getResultList();
        t.commit();
        return events;
    }
}
```

In store, when beginning a transaction, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
```

The shutdown method is not executed.
Why is the entity manager closed?

For the sake of completeness, here's the persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="pu">
        <class>com.lh.hibernateexample.Event</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myfirsthibernatedb" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="XXXXXXXX" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="XXXXXXXX" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the entity manager in your store method, and then try to close it again in shutdown method.

Using static methods in a DAO is weird.

Comment: That close should not be there, thanks. It was coming from a previous version. Why static methods are weird there?

Comment: you only need to use one entity manager, no need to keep creating for every method invocation. Static methods are harder to mock when writing unit tests.

Comment: I am actually creating the entity manager just once in the DBResourcesManager class, then I am just getting it. Not great style in DBResourcesManager, but still... Btw, my DAO has no state, so it seems reasonable it to have static methods.

Comment: you would normally inject the entity manager, your code would be hard to test.

Comment: I normally inject the entire dao, which becomes a singleton.

Comment: If I write the DAO myself, I test as usual (being singleton, no more static methods). If I rely on generated dao (e.g. Spring Repositories), it is even easier.